# link_to destroy using resources route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rest, ruby-on-rails-3.1

(No route matches [DELETE] "/subscriptions")

using

```
<%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscriptions_path(feed_id: session[:read_random].last), method: :delete, remote: :true %>
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :subscriptions
```

I need the link to actually have a URI of /subscriptions/1 using DELETE method but i can only seem to get /subscriptions?feed_id=1

Comment: you probably want `id: session[:read_random].last` then

Comment: Looks like that just changes the URL from localhost:3000/subscriptions?feed_id=1 to subscriptions?id=1

Comment: Method should be symbol :delete but remote should not be a symbol.Try changing the :true into true.Refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the id or object for delete:

```
<%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscription_path(session[:read_random].last), method: :delete, remote: :true %>
```

Comment: the session[:read_random] is an array of feed_ids that are previously read. so session[:read_random].last is actually returning an ID

Comment: @KenW Edited the answer to reflect this. Please try.

Comment: aha, I see what you're doing, sorry I missed that. I put it in and the URL turns into localhost/subscriptions.7 !!?!? why is it a period and not a slash?

Comment: Let's try the most basic version: `<%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', :controller => :subscriptions, :action => :destroy, :id => (session[:read_random].last), method: :delete %>`. See where this gets us.

Comment: no that wasnt right, brought me to the #show action... I did however try doing <%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscription_path(Subscription.find_by_feed_id(session[:read_random].last)), method: :delete, remote: :true %>  and it gives me the right link but for some reason it changes after using it once?!?!

Comment: Because you deleted the last id in the table but not in the session? You are almost there. Good luck. Gotta go.

Comment: Use this <%= link_to 'Unsubscribe', subscription_path(session[:read_random].last), :method => :delete %>

Comment: Yeah, skipping the `s` worked for me.. so using `subscription_path` and NOT `subscriptions_path`

Comment: @vajapravin : Changed subscriptions_path to subscription_path as corrected by you. Thanks.